# How to know which program is using the WebClient service?

Tags: windows, networking, services

I just found out by using TCPView that one of my svchost.exe had an http connection in "CLOSE_WAIT" to a strange IP address, although no other visible program was running.

With the help of Process Explorer I discovered that this svchost was using the WebClient Windows service.

I'm wondering how I can figure out what program used WebClient to connect to this IP, in order to determine if it's malware.

Comment: What was the IP address?

Comment: I don't think it's necessary to share it publicly.

Comment: How about proving the first two octets of the address (i.e. xxx.xxx of xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx)?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can find it out in this way:

1. Find out the destination port it is visiting.
2. Google the port and find out the related information, such as protocol, program.
3. If it does not resolve your problem, analyze the packets in detail.

Answer (score 0):

Webclient is a Microsoft service that allows Windows to access web-based files using an Explorer-like interface.  It's not required unless you need WebDAV-like access to remote web sites.  There's really no reason to suspect that it's malware.  Have you considered just disabling the service?  [Here are some useful details] (http://www.theeldergeek.com/webclient.htm). THIS APPARENTLY IS NOT A USEFUL LINK, SPAM PERHAPS